# Http.put does not accept any but a String

Tags: http, flutter, dart

Simple is, that I am trying to make a PUT request to my API but I get the type error of:

`_CastError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)`

My API accepts an Array of strings `(string[])`, which I know work because I am currently consuming it on the sibling web platform. So I am trying to replicate that on the Flutter app with the below code. At the moment it is just static code.

I know, that the `http` module is only accept string but is there a way to get around this? As it does not make sense, as what happens if we want to post an `int`, `bool` or `<List<String>>`. I know you can obviously convert using `.toString()` but my API has certain validation and is rigid on what it can accept.

Code below:

When I use this payload it works because it follows the rigid types of the Http module (`<String, String>`)

```
    Map<String, String> payloadThatWorks = {"first_name": "First Name"};
```

Now when I want to give the payload of the type `Map<String, List<String>>` with the code below:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> payload = {
      "personal_settings": ["allow-notification-discussion-mentions"]
    };
```

It throws the error of `_CastError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)`

in the `http.put` function below:

Main API Helper function

```
    static Future<http.Response> queryPut(String apiPath, {dynamic body}) async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');

        var response = await http.put(
             Uri.encodeFull(_urlBase + '$apiPath'),
             body: body,
             headers: {
                 HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $accessToken",
                 'Accept': 'application/json'
             },
         );

         return response;
    }
```

However, when helper function is called in my Widget...

```
http.Response response =
        await ApiService.queryPut('/api/users/$username', body: payload);
```

So i'm in a spot where the `http` module does not accept anything put `<String>` but the API does not accept anything but an Array or `<List<String>>`

How can I get round this or understand why the `http` put method is so rigid?

Thank you in advance :)

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can import dart:convert and use its jsonEncode to convert your map or array of map into a string

So basically you will have to do the following

```
String payloadStr = jsonEncode(payload)
```

and use this payloadStr to pass in the http methods. Similarly you can use JsonDecoder to convert json string to Map or Array of map.